# How to restrict some views/actions to logged in users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a new controller called Dashboard and a View called Index which says, Hello Username.

In MVC, how can I make this only available to logged in users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Authorize` attribute:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Comment: what about if I need it only for certain users or roles?

Comment: You can use the `Roles` parameters that I believe accepts a comma-delimited string.